# Editing Form inputs in php before adding databse

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a method that add products to db, i want to edit the product's name as product's url automatically. 
How it can be?

This is my form:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Product', array('type'=>'file')); ?>
        <fieldset>
            <legend><?php echo __('Add Product'); ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('category_id');
            echo $this->Form->input('name');
            echo $this->Form->input('Picture.0.name', array('type'=>'file'));
            echo $this->Form->input('description');
        ?>
        </fieldset>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

in product table in db there is a coloumn named url. i want take product's name and edit it and then save it as product's url.

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Product->create();
        $this->request->data['Product']['user_id'] = $this->member['id'];
        if ($this->Product->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The product has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The product could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $categories = $this->Product->Category->find('list');
    $users = $this->Product->User->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('categories', 'users'));
}
```

And this is my edit function:

```
function edit_url($input_str){
  $input_str = strtolower($input_str);
                                                // replaces other characters to en characters
  $input_str=str_replace('â', 'a', $input_str);
  $input_str=str_replace('ç', 'c', $input_str);
  $input_str=str_replace('ğ', 'g', $input_str);
  $input_str=str_replace('ı', 'i', $input_str);
  $input_str=str_replace('ö', 'o', $input_str);
  $input_str=str_replace('ş', 's', $input_str);
  $input_str=str_replace('ü', 'u', $input_str);
                                                // replaces spaces with -
  $input_str=str_replace(' ', '-', $input_str);
                                                // replaces symbols
  $input_str=str_replace('.', '', $input_str);
  $input_str=str_replace('/', '', $input_str);
  $input_str=str_replace('*', '', $input_str);
  $input_str=str_replace('+', '', $input_str);
  $input_str=str_replace('?', '', $input_str);

  return $input_str;
}
```

Comment: You can do this in Model beforeSave() function. Please check the cake manual.

Comment: It's not about beforeSave() function. in form there wasn't a place for user_id. I added it like that. I can do its job in those codes, here is an example as  you see above: 
        $this->request->data['Product']['user_id'] = $this->member['id'];

Comment: Please let me know how you save product name as url in db. you can use same code for edit process. You have not mention how you save page name as url. As i understand you are asking about slug?

Comment: yes yes it is about slug :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you can download cakephp Utility plugin under this url http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/utility 
then you should add this code in your model

```
        public $actsAs = array(
                'Utility.Sluggable' => array(
                    'field'     => 'title',  // Field that will be slugged
                    'slug'      => 'slug',  // Field that will be used for the slug
                    'lowercase' => true,    // Do we lowercase the slug ?
                    'separator' => '_',
                    'onUpdate'  =>  false//
                ));
```

You should also create a column as slug in your DB table.
Now if you want to change slug on updating data then you should pass 'onUpdate' =>  true  
This is for creating Unique slug 
Cakephp also proives some function you can check under this url http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/inflector.html

Inflector::slug($word, $replacement = '_')

Answer (score 0):

$this->request->data['Product']['url'] = $this->slugify($this->request->data['Product']['name']);

solved my problem. But there is anoher problem. If there are more than one products those have the same name...